# Custom segue transition with completion block & properties

Tags: ios, xcode, transition, segue, completion-block

I want to make a custom transition between view controllers, a slide from left to right like the iOS Basic Transition Effect between pages in the AppLaucher, but with a darkening.

I have a custom segue between viewControllers (let's call them FirstVC and SecondVC). For the darkening I have a black view which fade in during the animation (the SecondVC is darker than the FirstVC). I have a class - subclass of UIStoryboardSegue - for my custom segue, with the `-(void)perform` method implemented. In this method, I have implemented (with more details) :

```
//...Initials frames

UIView *blackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
blackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
blackView.alpha = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
blackView.alpha = 0.5;
//...Animations
}
completion:^(BOOL finished){

}];
```

I precise that the two View Controllers are in two different Navigation View Controllers.

For the darkening, I would like to modify the "darkView" property declared in the SecondVC class when the transition is finished, to store the darkening after the transition.

For this, I would like to do one of the following options (if one of those works I don't need the others) :

1. Access to the darkView property of the SecondVC directly in the completion block and modify it
2. Detect when the animation is finished and modify the property at that point, in a method implemented in the SecondVC class
3. Write `[dest.view addSubview:whiteView];` in the completion block ("dest" being the destination view controller), and access to THIS subview in an other method of SecondVC

I've already tried a lot of things for the three solutions, but I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well If you have a custom segue class implemented , then getting an instance of the secondViewController thats about to get pushed on the navigation stack should be simple.

Try this in your perform method

```
FirstViewController *firstVC = self.sourceViewController;
SecondViewController *secondVC = self.destinationViewController;
```

Probably you can declare a public UIView Property on your secondVC and access it and also probably expose a method and call it once the animation completes.

Comment: Thx for your help, but my segue is declared in the storyboard, wouldn't creating an intance programmatically interfere with the storyboard ?

Comment: You might have implemented your segue in your StoryBoard but you have to create a custom segue class to implement the Custom animation.
Create a subclass of UIStoryboardSegue and implement your perform method in that class. Don't forget to set this class as your custom segue class in the StoryBoard

Comment: When I try `FirstViewController *firstVC = self.sourceViewController` firstVC is of type UINavigationController. I think it's because the segue is linked with the Navigation Controller of secondVC, so segue.destinationViewController is the Navigation View Controller. What can I do ?

Comment: Hmmm why are you using two navigation Controllers ? You should ideally be using one NavigationController which manages the FirstVC and SecondVC . And your FirstVC should be set as the rootviewController to the Navigation Controller.

Comment: I have 5 View Controllers in my application. The first manage 2VC (with FirstVC -> initial VC), and the other 3VC (with SecondVC). I use 2 Navigation Controller because I want the 3VC to be a kind of temporary pop-up, but I don't really understand the Navigation Controller, maybe I don't have to do that but I've seen people doing it. Actually, I have push segue transition between the View Controllers within each Navigation Controller and I have modal transition when I change of Navigation Controller. I though it was more logic to have 2 Navigation Controllers, but you say it's not necessary ?

Comment: So basically a NavigationController is a manager to all the viewControllers. It manages them in terms of a stack methodology i.e Push and Pop. With your kind of setup you can implement it with using a single NavigationController and since you are trying to provide a custom animation you can very easily bring the effect of a pop up while your pushing the viewController on the stack. But then again theres no harm using two navigationControllers , its just that you need to be cautious while managing them.

Comment: And I think I found out why your getting an instance of a navigation Controller for the secondVC. So to fix that you can say
`UINavigationController *secondNav = self.destinationViewController;
 `
`UIViewController *secondVC = [[secondNav viewControllers] firstObject];`

Comment: Whis this, I have a simple View Controller so I can't access to the property. If I implement `SecondViewController *secondVC = (SecondViewController *)[[secondNav viewControllers] firstObject];` I get : `'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<SecondViewController: 0x8c9a1f0> should have parent view controller:<FirstViewController: 0x8f912d0> but actual parent is:<UINavigationController: 0x8c74550>'`

Comment: Well , these are the ambiguities which occur when when you have more than one navigation controllers managing your viewController Hierarchy. It could be that your trying to push in a navigation controller into an already existing navigationController. Try resolving your design by using a single navigationController.It will workout how you expect to.

Comment: It works with one Navigation Controller, thanks a lot !